# how to use SOFR as risk free rate in portfolio construction

Tags: sharpe-ratio, risk-free, sofr

Good afternoof to everyone.
I would like to create a portfolio following a multifactorial approach (I have been writing my master's thesis). As I would like to calculate a series of ratios (e.g. Sharpe ratio), I need a risk-free rate for the US market and I would like to use SOFR as an alternative to LIBOR.
Now, I have downloaded the time series of the WEEKLY prices, how should I consider the SOFR? It is currently 0.09% but does it mean daily? Or is it yearly / monthly?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOFR quote is annualized rate.

Comment: where can I find this? I only found the daily value, or at 30/190/180 days. In any case, I changed the price series, using the monthly one. Do you think I can consider, at this point, the 30-day value of the SOFR that I found here https://apps.newyorkfed.org/markets/autorates/sofr-avg-ind to calculate the Sharpe ratio?

Comment: The daily data is here: https://apps.newyorkfed.org/markets/autorates/SOFR

Comment: With SOFR at 9bp, the difference between Sharpe with/without should be minimal. If I were to include a RFR in Sharpe calculation, I would use the return on cash that I could get if I were not invested. This could be EFFR, LIBOR or SOFR less some spread. I'm skeptical it even makes sense to include the RFR as the alternative to investing in a risky strategy is generally not investing in the RFR but in another risky strategy.

Comment: thank you so much for the advice!